# beforeEach not executing in jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

```
describe('DropDown', () => {
  let store: any;
  let wrapper: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      dropDown: {
        ...
      },
    });
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <DropDown />
      </Provider>
    );
  });

  it('Search should update the list', () => {
    const searchField = wrapper.find('.textInput');
    searchField.simulate('change', {
      target: {
        value: 'First customer',
      },
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.customersList .list li').length).toBe(1);
  });
})
```

and I get a `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` on `wrapper` element in the `it` block. Why? If I update the `let wrapper: any = null` it then switches to `cannot read property on null` so the `beforeEach` block isn't calling. Anybody knows why?

**EDIT:** I liked @colinux answer so I accepted it, but my actual cause was that the `store` object `dropDown` had been renamed and for some reason it broke down things that had nothing to do with it.

Comment: `beforeEach`,  `store` and `wrapper` variable declarations should be made outside the `describe` block

Comment: @LoXatoR that doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried adding a console.log(), in the beforeEach?

Comment: @LoXatoR yeah and there is no output, as if the `beforeEach` block wasn't even there

Comment: It's weird, it worked for me when I tried your block of code on my environment. Is it compiling correctly? Any import or syntax issues?

Comment: @Xeen do any of the other books fire e.g. `before` / `after` / `afterEach`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the way Jest execute tests (because of mocks and parallelism among others), it's not safe to assign outside variables in `beforeEach` and friends.

Instead, for this kind of pattern, it's better to define a common method and calling it manually in each test.

```js
describe('DropDown', () => {
  function prepare() {
    const store = mockStore({
      dropDown: {},
    });

    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <DropDown />
      </Provider>,
    );

    return { store, wrapper };
  }

  it('Search should update the list', () => {
    const { wrapper } = prepare();

    const searchField = wrapper.find('.textInput');
    searchField.simulate('change', {
      target: {
        value: 'First customer',
      },
    });

    expect(wrapper.find('.customersList .list li').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

The `prepare` method return variables usable in tests. Each test can get what it need. You can also improve the method with optional parameters if, saying, for a test you need to create a slightly different store.

EDIT: this pattern is described in details with testing-library here https://kentcdodds.com/blog/avoid-nesting-when-youre-testing